# UIReturnKeyDone return or other feedback?

Tags: objective-c, uikeyboard

So I'm using textfield.returnKeyTYpe = UIReturnKeyDone in my code with my UIKeyboard. The problem that I am running into is that the done button and the hide keyboard button are both performing the same function in that, once they are clicked the keyboard hides but the program continues on to the next field and the keyboard pops up right away.

I want to know if there is something that the UIReturnKeyDone returns when clicked that I can grab to differentiate between clicking the Done key and the hide keyboard key.

Sorry if that does't make sense, I am new to all this.

Comment: Presumably this is on iPad, since the iPhone doesn't have a hide keyboard button?

Comment: correct, it is on the iPad

Comment: Which text field delegate methods are you implementing? I don't know the answer to this question, but it probably lies in there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It now make sense, You need to create UIButton and press it to hide keyboard.

When you want to hide keyboard.

[textView resignFirstResponder];